# Page scrolls horizontaly while user scrolls down or to the right. How can i replicate that?

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow, horizontal-scrolling

So i am currently building a portfolio website and my horizontal (overflow x: auto) scroll doesnt work with a mousewheel. The following website has managed to do both: https://www.emilygarthwaite.com/overview#20

I tried to rebuild the html and css of the bespoken page, but i couldnt achieve the same result.

I wasnt able to recreate it with my website. I am using webflow to build it, if that is of any relevance. If this question seems a little general, I am sorry! I am new to html, css and js.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand with your question, you need to set the height explicitly(`style="height: 989px;"`), and then you can add `overflow-x:auto` and adjust other css properties accordingly. This enables horizontal scrolling if the content exceeds the defined height. You may need to check how to use a carousel effect. Your question doesn't show the exact issue without any code sample your trying to accomplish your result. Check this also.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft

Comment: I should have specified a little more, overflow x is working for me. The problem is that it only comfortably works with a trackpad, because i can scroll sideways with it. I cant scroll sideways with the mousewheel just like that. The mentioned website scrolls horizontaly on down and right scroll, which is what i would like my own website to have.

Comment: The website i am currently building is this one, i have tried all sorts of js code snippets, but none of them worked: https://meghana-geetha.webflow.io/